# extracting lines from a file with C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a text file1 and I wish to extract lines (which don't exist in file2)in a new file3

example :

file1:

```
/**
* Gets the total volume.
*
* @return the total volume
*/
public int getTotalVolume() {return totalVolume;}
```

file2:

```
* Gets the total volume.
*
* @return the total volume
```

file3:

```
/**
 */
public int getTotalVolume() {return totalVolume;}
```

my function:

```
    public void Traitv2(string file1, string file2, string file3)
    {
        StreamReader monStreamReaderfile1 = new StreamReader(file1);
        StreamWriter monStreamWriterfile3 = new StreamWriter(file3);
        string ligne = monStreamReaderfile1.ReadLine();

        while (ligne != null)
        {
            StreamReader monStreamReaderfile2 = new StreamReader(file2);
            string ligne1 = monStreamReaderfile2.ReadLine();
            while (ligne1 != null)
            {
                if (!ligne.Equals(ligne1))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(ligne);
                    monStreamWriterfile3.WriteLine(ligne);
                }

                ligne1 = monStreamReaderfile2.ReadLine();
                ligne = monStreamReaderfile1.ReadLine();
            }

            ligne = monStreamReaderfile1.ReadLine();
            monStreamReaderfile2.Close();
        }

        monStreamWriterfile3.Close();
        monStreamReaderfile1.Close();
    }
```

When I run this function, the result is false and an error occurs: error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution using Linq:

```
var file1 = File.ReadAllLines("file1name");
var file2 = File.ReadAllLines("file2name");
var file3 = file1.Except(file2);
File.WriteAllLines("fileName3", file3);
```

Comment: this will load whole of the file in memory.

Comment: that is not necessarily a problem

Comment: @ParvSharma: that's true but at least one file has to be loaded in memory (e.g. file 2) unless you want to read it again and again for each line to check...

Comment: but can be. The solution overall isnt efficient and from what i get from reading the code dosent answers what the questioner whants

Comment: @Raidri: the result is not written to a file, you should add this: `File.WriteAllLines("fileName3", file3);`

Comment: @BasBrekelmans - from what i think what the code is trying to do is to check wether each line(ie line number wise) is equal to the line at the same line number of another file. where as except will check this across whole of the file

Comment: thats the difference between this code and code given by @Damith

Comment: @ParvSharma: if you look at the example provided by the questioner, it does not compare line by line while the provided code example does. But the OP said the code doesn't work and that's probably one of the reason...

Comment: that is a problem because the files are too long and i really need to use my function

Answer (score 1):

This solution will read file2 into an array and then read/write line by line based on if file2 contains the line.

```
public void Traitv2(string file1, string file2, string file3)
{
    var file2Lines = File.ReadAllLines(file2);

    IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(file1)
                                    .Where(line => !file2Lines.Contains(line));
    File.WriteAllLines(file3, lines);
}
```

Comment: +1 This is more efficient since it loads just file 2 into memory

Comment: thanks to all of you for your answers!! i think i will use this solution

Comment: BTW, you can further improve performances by replacing the first line with: `var file2Lines = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines(file2));`

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void Traitv2(string file1, string file2, string file3)
    {
        string line1;
        string line2;
        using (var reader1 = new StreamReader(file1))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file3))
        {
            while ((line1 = reader1.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                using (var reader2 = new StreamReader(file2))
                {
                    while ((line2 = reader2.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (!line1.Equals(line2))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check for null at the `strings` you get to the function and more impotently `StreamReader` and the line you read

you are getting null because of the line:

```
ligne = monStreamReaderfile1.ReadLine();
```

inside the while loop.

the file got to the end and you try to read.
check null before your line

```
if (!ligne.Equals(ligne1))
```

here is the full answer code

```
public void Traitv2(string file1, string file2, string file3)
{
    StreamReader monStreamReaderfile1 = new StreamReader(file1);
    StreamWriter monStreamWriterfile3 = new StreamWriter(file3);
    string ligne = monStreamReaderfile1.ReadLine();

    while (ligne != null)
    {
        StreamReader monStreamReaderfile2 = new StreamReader(file2);
        string ligne1 = monStreamReaderfile2.ReadLine();
        while (ligne1 != null)
        {
            if (ligne != null && !ligne.Equals(ligne1))
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ligne);
                monStreamWriterfile3.WriteLine(ligne);
            }

            ligne1 = monStreamReaderfile2.ReadLine();
            ligne = monStreamReaderfile1.ReadLine();
        }

        ligne = monStreamReaderfile1.ReadLine();
        monStreamReaderfile2.Close();
    }

    monStreamWriterfile3.Close();
    monStreamReaderfile1.Close();
}
```

Comment: the problem is in the line : if (!ligne.Equals(ligne1)) and i don't understand why ligne takes null

Answer (score 0):

this solution is most likely to get you the error you are complaining of because
1.first you are checking ligne1!=null in a while statement.
2.then inside it you are checking for non nullability of ligne2 and increasing and using both ligne1 and ligne2

```
    while (ligne1 != null)
                {
                    if (!ligne.Equals(ligne1))
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(ligne);
                        monStreamWriterfile3.WriteLine(ligne);
                    }

                    ligne1 = monStreamReaderfile2.ReadLine();
                    ligne = monStreamReaderfile1.ReadLine(); 
                    //here you are incrementing ligne but not 
                    //checking nullabllity
            }
```